# Realtek RTL8821AE Wifi driver/alternative

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I recently built a new computer using an ASROCK motherboard, which comes with a realtek RTL8821AE PCI-E wireless module.  I installed [elementary os](http://elementaryos.org/), just to try something new.  It didn't recognize the wifi device out of the box, but after some searching I came across the [Linux drivers](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/rtl819x#Realtek_802.11n_drivers) page, which indicates that a driver is available for my card in kernel 3.16+, so I downloaded kernel 3.16 and installed it.  Now, `lsmod` shows that I have the rtl8821ae driver installed, and `lshw` shows that the device exists but is `unclaimed', which means that the driver isn't working correctly.  After a bit more digging, I came across [this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-driver-devel/msg51489.html) post, which seems to indicate that the rtl8821ae driver isn't fully functioning yet.

My question is this: 
 1. Should I keep digging and try to get the driver working?  If so, any suggestions on how to get an installed driver to actually do its job?
 b. Should I just order a PCI-E wifi card with known Linux support? If so, any suggestions?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issues with a RealTek of similar vintage (and if you Google this, you will see others also have issues). In my experience, you can't go wrong with Intel. I have a a 6205 on my laptop. This  card has gotten good reviews and is compatible per the comments: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833106033

Comment: I just ordered an [Intel 5100 PCI-E](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00HUIJ4H0/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_2?pf_rd_p=1535523722&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B001EH8H9E&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=1F6ANPS2ZZXNTM7Q75RF) to replace the RealTek...it was only $10 and it seems to have good Linux drivers.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Didn't realize you could use a mini card, but I'm sure you will be good on this...

Comment: It's a mini itx mobo.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [this](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) driver from `iwfinger`.
To install it, open a terminal and type the following commands:

Note:get Internet connection or download the drivers from another computer and move them to your current computer via the link below.

1. Download drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential git
   git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
   ```
2. Install drivers:

   ```
   cd ./rtlwifi_new
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
   ```
3. Replace `rtl8821ae` in last command with your chip model. To see your rtlwifi chip model use:

   ```
   lspci | grep Wireless
   ```

   or

   ```
   lspci
   ```

This driver will make your rtlwifi card more stable and usable. I use it for my Asus E202S which had lot of bugs with wifi.

Comment: The repo doesn't seem to exist anymore? Anyone got a fork?

Answer (score 1):

Buying a known-working card is a much better idea, specially if you want access point (AP) mode. In general, the Intel cards are very good. http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

This is a very valuable wiki which details which devices /drivers work, and in which kernel they were introduced.
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users

Comment: I forgot that I had asked this.  I did indeed end up getting an Intel wifi link 5100 and that solved all my (wifi related) issues.  Thanks!